# ADODB, VBScript, ASP, SELECT not working with WHERE

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

My SELECT statement works until I add a WHERE parameter.
When I have the WHERE parameter added I get a 500 error.
Again, This works correctly unless I add a WHERE parameter to the select statement.

```
<html>
<body>

<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

Dim db_path
Dim db_dir
db_dir = Server.MapPath("/private") & "\"
db_path = db_dir & "Database.mdb" 

conn.Open db_path

set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT DISTINCT Group, Finish FROM Parts WHERE Group = 'Exhaust'"

rs.Open sql, conn
%>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<%response.write(sql)%>
  <tr>
  <%for each x in rs.Fields
    response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
  next%>
  </tr>
  <%do until rs.EOF%>
    <tr>
    <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
      <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
    <%next
    rs.MoveNext%>
    </tr>
  <%loop
  rs.close
  conn.close%>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are only selecting the 'exhaust' group there is no need to have 'distinct group' in the select portion of the query.

Comment: There are multiple rows with the same value for Group, some of those rows have the same values for the Finish column. And they all have unique values for other columns. There would be duplicate rows returned without distinct. I only want one result for each Finish from the selected group.

Comment: My problem seemed to come from using the word "Group". I didn't have to format the sql statement this way when using other words.

Comment: So why not just "SELECT DISTINCT FINISH"? I still don't understand why you need to select group where group = a specific value.

Comment: I see what you mean, no, I did not need to select Group since it was already a known value. But that was not related to the problem I was having. My issue seems to have come from using "Group" with WHERE.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it.
It works if I change the select statement to this:

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT Group, Finish FROM Parts WHERE (((Group)='Exhaust'));"
```